# Is there a display manager that allows setup of wifi connection before logging in?

Tags: wifi, xorg, networkmanager, ldap, lxdm

I'm working on a pam_ldap solution for laptop users, but of course it won't work unless wifi is connected. I won't know ahead of time what wifi network users will be on.

I want to emulate how chromebooks work, where you can connect to wifi before actually logging in.

Current distro is GalliumOS (Xubuntu variant) using lxdm.

Comment: Pleae add distro.

Comment: Using Ubuntu, but I'd still be curious if any other distros have a solution.

Comment: Network services should be able to that, like Network Manger with proper settings, enabled as system service.

Comment: Link? Would that allow the user to select the wifi network before login?

Comment: I don't know of any display managers that do that, but you can generally set your system up to automatically connect to the internet on bootup, i.e. you'd be connected before you'd even get to the display manager... Granted they have to login to the network once before it can be automated like that.

Comment: You didn't say how your wifi is setup (different logins for different users?), but one option is to either have a general wifi/services login, or a login per machine (laptop). In that way, the machine can connect to the wifi when it boots (the DM doesn't need to do that, and shouldn't), pam_ldap will work, and they can re-login to wifi/other services when logged on if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Credentials can be cached on PAM.

A possible solution is requiring the users to login once in a while, in a non-authenticated network, and setup auto-login in the machines in an area in the office wifi network/via ethernet so credentials can be cached.

PS. This also requires the helpdesk office to have a couple of non-authenticathed network ethernet points to debug problems.